# Spotify Client Credentials Flow using Python

Tags: python, spotify

I'm trying to get a token using Spotify's Client Credentials Flow and Python, however I just get the following:

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client"}

I'm following this guide - https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/

Using this example script as a starting point - https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_requests_post_headers

Here's my code (I've changed the Base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key):

```
import requests

url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
myobj = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

#use the 'headers' parameter to set the HTTP headers:
x = requests.post(url, data = myobj, headers = {"Authorization": "Basic Base64EncodedStringHere==","Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

print(x.text)
```

If I change the last line to print(x), I just get: <Response [400]>

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while following a tutorial but I manage to find a solution on the Spotify community.

```
import requests

import base64

client_id = "your client id here"
client_secret = "your client secret here"

encoded = base64.b64encode((client_id + ":" + client_secret).encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")

headers = {
     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded
}
 
payload = {
     "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
 
response = requests.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Please, highlight the code to make your answer more clear.